# how to log time taken by jdbc components

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jdbc

In my spring integration application i have several stored-proc-outbound-gateway, i would to log how much time each call is taking, any help would be appreciated. 
I would ideally like to be able to enable/disable logging for the parameters used, time taken and total rows retrieved (returning-resultset) to monitor and performance tuning purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `ChannelInterceptor` (subclass of `ChannelInterceptorAdapter`) to the request channel which will give you raw timing (preSend/postSend), but the time will include any processing downstream of the gateway (on direct channels).

Since you want to examine the results too, you could start a timer (e.g. Spring `StopWatch`) in the interceptor (preSend) on the request channel and stop the timer in an interceptor on the reply channel). If you use the same interceptor bean you can store the timer in a `ThreadLocal`.

You can turn on/off collection using a boolean property on the interceptor.

Alternatively, you can add a [custom advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) to the gateway.

**EDIT**

The advice is probably the best approach because with a `ThreadLocal` you will need to add code to the first interceptor to handle failures and clean up. With an around advice, the timer would just be a local method variable.